# Python Pandas if statement based on numeric and string condistions

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, syntax-error, conditional-statements

Working with the dataframe df:

```
ID | Category | Price
23      A       101
34      B       50
24      A       55
```

I want to add a flag, for all Category A and Price less and equal to 100.

This is my code:

```
df['Flag'][(df['Price'] <=100)&(df['Category']=='A')] = 'X'
```

I get this error:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

When I try to filter on the flag, I get this error:

```
df.loc[df['Flag'] == 'X']

TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

Expected Output:

```
ID | Category | Price  Flag
23      A       101     
34      B       50
24      A       55       X
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `loc`

```
df.loc[(df['Price'] <=100)&(df['Category']=='A'), "Flag"] = 'X'
```

Comment: Im gettingthis error now AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'loc'

Comment: you have to apply `loc` on your data frame object. Are you sure you're doing `df.loc`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map()`:

```
>>> df['flag'] = ((df['Category'] == 'A') & (df['Price'] <= 100)).map({True: 'X', False: ''})
>>> df
   ID Category  Price flag
0  23        A    101
1  34        B     50
2  24        A     55    X
```